# Which Classifier to Use When Each class has only one image

Tags: classification, svm, face-recognition

I am trying to classify Facenet embedding using one image per class. I am getting very low accuracy even with small number of classes.

Current I am using SVM to classify embeddings. Is there a better classifier which works great on one image per class with thousands of classes?